# How to set cell values with an array of data in EPPlus?

Tags: excel, epplus

I've tried searching but I cannot seem to find a way to set a range of values using an array.

Do I have to use a double loop to do  this? Is there no way to use a multidimensional array for it like in Google App Scripts? In particular, I am looking for similar functionality to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range#setValues in EPPlus.

Comment: double loop is the best way on this. If you have to use this time and time, let's try to create a function to do it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A double loop is the only way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly of interest. I found [ExcelRangeBase.LoadFromArrays and LoadFromCollection](https://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EPPlus/ExcelRangeBase.cs) but the implementation uses a double loop...